# Smtp Server default timeout

Tags: email, smtp, sendmail

In case the destination mail server is temporarily down, how much time would my own mail server keep retrying sending the mail before giving up? I would love to know the default timeout value if it is mentioned in the RFC (which I could not figure out).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Sendmail documentation](http://www.sendmail.org/~ca/email/doc8.12/op-sh-4.html) in `Message timeouts` sections references [RFC1123](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1123.txt)

[RFC1123](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1123.txt)

> **Requirements for Internet Hosts -- Application and Support**
>   ...
>   5.3.1  SMTP Queueing Strategies
>   ...
>   5.3.1.1 Sending Strategy
>   ... Retries continue until the message is transmitted or the sender gives up; the give-up time generally needs to be at least 4-5 days. ...